# Mongodb dynamic geo queries

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

Mongodb geo queries allows to query documents within some geometry (box, circle, polygon), but geomerty param is static.

In my application geometry parameters depends on each document. Is it possible to solve this with Mongodb geo queries or not?

For example: Dealer is working in some region described by polygon. I need to find all dealers for my current location.

Comment: It seems that it is impossible. Currently we choose postgis and postgres database

Comment: no takers for this one? Darn... I want to know too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to dynamically specify different geometries when the query is executing, as per the documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-BoundsQueries).

However, you could do something like convert all the polygons to a box that approximates the bounding area of the n-sided polygon you have for each dealer. Then, just use a box for all of them. It isn't perfect but it works and solves the problem.